# NodeJS - How to properly install and run Webpack on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webpack

I downloaded existing Web project and tried to run:
webpack --watch --progress

but it keeps saying:

```
webpack --watch --progress
One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): yes
Installing 'webpack-cli' (running 'npm install -D webpack-cli')...
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.10.2 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-codemirror@1.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.1.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-codemirror@1.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.1.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-codemirror@1.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.1.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.11.3 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ webpack-cli@3.1.2
added 2 packages from 2 contributors, removed 1 package, updated 3 packages and audited 24726 packages in 16.453s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at runCommand.then (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:142:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Does WebPack require specific NPM/Node version? (maybe newer version is not compatible with older one)..

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305211

Oleg Pro's help did the trick for me, specifically putting `node_modules/.bin` in my path as he describes in part 3.

With my versions of webpack (4.29.0) and Node (v10.15.0), I didn't find `node_modules/.bin/webpack-cmd` (as he specifies in 1.) in my project directory; I found `node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli`.

The install appears to work, as I then used webpack to install Vue, which in turn generated `app.vue` and `hello_vue.js` files. However, `vue --version` returns `vue:command` not found, so I'm adopting a wait and see attitude.